# htaccess single page rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, singlepage

I've created a single page website (www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr) and I'm trying to do some fancy url rewriting in .htaccess.

My page basically has 6 sections defined by div ids.

I would like to write a rule that translates :

```
www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/portfolio
```

into

```
www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/index.php#portfolio
```

and that would also work without the www.

I've looked around for a solution I could use but couldn't really find anything that fits. Although I plan to properly learn regular expression at some point I only have very basic knowledge on the subject at the time.

I've been using that for some time but it stopped working and now brings me to my error page:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /#$1 [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

I should mention I currently have this rule to send www.domain.com > domain.com

```
# REDIRECTION (tout vers le www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would appreciate your thoughts on the subject.

Thanks in advance !!

Romain

Here is the rest of my .htaccess file if it can help

```
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

RewriteEngine on

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Error pages
ErrorDocument 404 /erreur.php
ErrorDocument 403 /erreur.php
Options -Indexes

# REDIRECTION (tout vers www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# REDIRECTION de .xxx.fr/portfolio vers xxx.fr/index.php#portfolio
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /#$1 [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your last rule actually changes non-www to www so `domain.com` > `www.domain.com`

Comment: right that's what I meant, sorry I wrote it the other way around.

Comment: You rules above seem to be fine, when you try go to `www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/index.php#portfolio` it brings you to the error page?

Comment: When I go to www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/index.php#portfolio it works, I get taken to the right place.

Comment: but if you go to `www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/portfolio` it won't work?

Comment: right, I've taken the line down because it takes me to my /erreur.php page

Comment: Try putting that line above the error pages?

Comment: It's even more stupid than that !! I've messed up my config of git-ftp and I wasn't uploading to the right place... It actually works !!!. When I do something like http://www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/contact it gets converted to http://www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/#contact. Do you know if there's anyway I could hide the redirect so it would still appear as : http://www.lelaboratoiredeco.fr/contact

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry I've been taking up some of your time for a stupid config mistake !

Answer (score 0):

To keep the `/contact`, `/portfiolio` etc in the  url remove the `R=301` from the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /#$1 [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Will become:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /#$1 [NC,NE,L]
```

It should work

Comment: If I remove the R=301 it doesn't work anymore. It works if I only leave R without the 301 but I originally put the 301 for search engines because I wanted them to index xx.fr/contact not xx.fr/#contact